# Enable HP Coolsense on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, hp, overheating, temperature

I own a HP laptop with HP coolsense. I use Ubuntu on it as my only operating system. I have noticed the computer has been getting extremely hot, and I am beginning to worry if it is damaging the computer. Is there a program I can use compatible with HP's coolsense to adjust the fan speed and other related temperature problems?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no alternative to HP "coolsense", but if you want to control fan speeds follow these steps:

first you need a way to monitor system temperature and fan speeds

> sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
>   sudo sensors-detect

answer yes to all questions and reboot

> sudo pwmconfig

follow the instructions and

> sudo sensors -s

to check the temperature run:

> sensors

to run fan control run:

> sudo /usr/sbin/fancontrol &

if you are running ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 then sensors will be present in the top bar

[source: tuxtweaks](http://tuxtweaks.com/2008/08/how-to-control-fan-speeds-in-ubuntu/)